# How to listen to registry key value changes?

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

I want to track if a value of the registry key changes. Maybe something like [notify](https://docs.rs/notify/latest/notify/index.html#examples) but for registry.
Right now I'm getting registry value with help of windows-registry.

code:

```rust
pub fn is_light_theme() -> bool {
    let val = CURRENT_USER
        .open(r#"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"#)
        .expect("Failed to get registry key")
        .get_u32("AppsUseLightTheme")
        .expect("Failed to get registry value");
    println!("{}", val);
    val != 0
}
```

Comment: What does recursively mean in this context?

Comment: Having an option to listen to changes of several keys. For example listen for changes of all keys in registry path "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize".

Comment: I will remove recursively because I am not sure if used it correctly. Having an option to listen to several keys is just nice to have

Comment: [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue) is the only user-mode API available to monitor registry changes (a kernel-mode filter driver can [register for notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/registering-for-notifications) that provide more information). Either way, this isn't the right way to do it anyway. The [`UISettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings) class is the official and supported system interface.

Comment: @IInspectable
Your comment is the answer to my question, you can post it if you want.